# Cannot install Gensim in Conda env - noarch directory not found

Tags: python, windows, configuration, conda, channel

I am working on a remote server in a Conda environment.  So I had previously installed Gensim and had been using it but the other day I ran into this error:

[image: Gensim error]

No big deal I'll just `!conda install` it again:

[image: The error to end all errors]

```python
import sys

!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} gensim
Solving environment: ...working... failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/noarch/noarch/repodata.json>
Elapsed: 00:00.438028
CF-RAY: 4b676bdb1fa378c8-LAX

The remote server could not find the noarch directory for the
requested channel with url: https://conda.anaconda.org/noarch

As of conda 4.3, a valid channel must contain a `noarch/repodata.json` and
associated `noarch/repodata.json.bz2` file, even if `noarch/repodata.json` is
empty. please request that the channel administrator create
`noarch/repodata.json` and associated `noarch/repodata.json.bz2` files.
$ mkdir noarch
$ echo '{}' > noarch/repodata.json
$ bzip2 -k noarch/repodata.json

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state.
Further configuration help can be found at <https://conda.io/docs/config.html>.
```

Okay let's follow directions:

[image: follow directions]

```bash
mkdir noarch
A subdirectory or file noarch already exists.

echo '{}' > noarch/repodata.json

bzip2 -k noarch/repodata.json
  File "<ipython-input-5-cad6ef02410f>", line 1
    bzip2 -k noarch/repodata.json
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Fine consult Dr. Google: show channels

[image: google taught me everything I know]

```bash
!conda config --show channels
channels:
  - noarch
  - conda-forge
  - K183152
  - k183152
  - win-64
  - default
  - pysoundfile
  - loopbio
  - defaults

!conda config --add channels
usage: conda config [-h] [--json] [--debug] [--verbose]
                    [--system | --env | --file FILE]
                    (--show [SHOW [SHOW ...]] | --show-sources | --validate | --describe [DESCRIBE [DESCRIBE ...]] | --write-default | --get [KEY [KEY ...]] | --append KEY VALUE | --prepend KEY VALUE | --set KEY VALUE | --remove KEY VALUE | --remove-key KEY | --stdin)
conda config: error: argument --prepend/--add: expected 2 arguments

!conda config --get
--set auto_update_conda False
--add channels 'defaults'   # lowest priority
--add channels 'loopbio'
--add channels 'pysoundfile'
--add channels 'default'
--add channels 'win-64'
--add channels 'k183152'
--add channels 'K183152'
--add channels 'conda-forge'
--add channels 'noarch'   # highest priority
--set ssl_verify True
```

Well at least I can code on my own machine - oh wow it downgraded Python in my Jupyter Notebook:

[image: downgraded python]

More google:

[image: try sys.executable and sys.path]

```ipython
sys.path
Out[9]: 
['C:\\Users\\k183152',
 'C:\\Users\\k183152\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\k183152\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\k183152\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\k183152\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3',
 '',
 'C:\\Users\\k183152\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\k183152\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\k183152\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\k183152\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\k183152\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\k183152\\.ipython']

!conda install -c conda-forge gensim
Solving environment: ...working... failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/noarch/noarch/repodata.json>
Elapsed: 00:00.824175
CF-RAY: 4b677075fe382300-LAX

The remote server could not find the noarch directory for the
requested channel with url: https://conda.anaconda.org/noarch

As of conda 4.3, a valid channel must contain a `noarch/repodata.json` and
associated `noarch/repodata.json.bz2` file, even if `noarch/repodata.json` is
empty. please request that the channel administrator create
`noarch/repodata.json` and associated `noarch/repodata.json.bz2` files.
$ mkdir noarch
$ echo '{}' > noarch/repodata.json
$ bzip2 -k noarch/repodata.json

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state.
Further configuration help can be found at <https://conda.io/docs/config.html>.



sys.executable
Out[11]: 'C:\\Users\\k183152\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\python.exe'
```

Well maybe Gensim won't install because NumPy OR SciPy didn't install?  - really shooting in the dark at this point: no they're fine

I'm still getting the same stubborn noarch directory requested channel error - I don't know how to fix it please help :(

Comment: Hello, Sara. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide any outputs/code/error messages in the question itself as *formatted text*. However, it seems like in your *follow directions* link, you are trying to enter shell commands directly into a Jupyter notebook, but that will be interpreted as *Python code*, so it will fail (hence the SyntaxErrors). I believe you'll need to do `!<shell command as googled>` and Jupyter will run the command as a shell. Or just use a terminal.

Comment: Note, that may be confusing because Jupyter Notebooks recognize common shell commands without the !, e.g. `ls` and `pwd` and `cd`

Comment: !bzip2 -k noarch/repodata.json
'bzip2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Do your u have `bzip2`? Sounds like you are on Windows, you might have to find instructions specifically for windows

Comment: I don't believe so where can I download it?  I have limited resources as I'm working off of Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you there. You should definitely tag this with windows.

Comment: Can you please check if gensim really is missing from the env (`conda list | grep gensim`)? I suspect perhaps your Python version changed and that's causing the package missing issue. I'd guess the most efficient solution might be to revert the env to a working state. I.e., look at your revisions (`conda list -r`), then find one before your Python version changed and install it (`conda install --revision <n>`).

Comment: Gensim isn't in the list let me try revision

Comment: I've read a few other similar errors that talked about removing the noarch channel but the command given isn't working:                                             !conda config --remove channels 'noarch'

CondaKeyError: 'channels': "'noarch'" is not in the 'channels' key of the config file                                                                                                                                   - but it's totally in the channels list.

Comment: I tried revision, but not only do I only have revision 0 I get the same the remote server couldn't find the directory error that I received before when I !conda install --revision 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out - those added channels gotta go.  Navigate to .condarc I found it in my user directory and edit it in notepad.  Delete those channels and save.

[image: Solution .condarc]